# Database design to allow storing data from foreign relationships that might change

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I will try to describe what I want to accomplish, a solution I found and would be glad on your input/suggestions.

I have these two tables:

```
InvoiceType
-----------
invoice_type_id PK
type_name
line
show_in_income
..(other attributes)..
```

and

```
Invoice
-------
invoice_id PK
invoice_type_id FK
..(other attributes)..
```

Let's say we have the following entries:

```
someInvoiceType: (1, "some name", "A", 1, ...)  
    someInvoice: (1, 1, ...)
```

What I want is that even if an attribute of the **someInvoiceType** is edited and for example *"some name"* changes to *"some other name"*, the **someInvoice** that was created while it had the *first value*, to keep the old one.

So my (kind of obvious) solution was to have a separate table to store the data from InvoiceType, which might change and I want to keep:

```
InvoiceInfo
------------
invoice_info_id PK
invoice_id FK
type_name
line
show_in_expenses
```

which will be filled only when an Invoice is created and thus will be used to retrieve all the info that I might want and wont rely on any changes.

What worries me is that this solution seems kinda "static" and not really expandable, in case I want to store more attribute info.

As I said in the beginning I would really like some suggestions/opinions on my occasion and even better design approaches.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem in ERP systems: invoices must not change after being issued, no matter what.

There are 2 commonly used solutions:

1. Denormalise. In the invoice table simply save every information that is relevant for the invoice, not just the foreign keys to other lookup tables. This is the most foolproof solution, since you directly have to manipulate the invoice table if you want to modify anything in it. Moreover, this is the most efficient from query perspective as well, as you do not need complicated queries to find the relevant data in the historic versions of the lookup tables.
2. Versioning. The relevant lookup tables need to store version history, so with a query you can look up what was the valid parameter when the invoice was created. This would save you from denormalising the invoice table, but queries would get a lo complicated, since you have to be able to locate the historic versions of each related data in lookup tables.

Comment: I guess I could go back and denormalise, it does indeed make some operations simpler and faster.  
Apart from the time and query complexity, is there any other advantage in this solution over the one I have right now? 
Or to phrase it better, does my way provide any advantage (that you can think of) over your first solution?
Thanks a lot for your time and response!

Comment: The advantage of the versioning solution is that it is not denormalised :) With versioning you can track the changes of the parameters (think about pricing for example), with denormalisation you may loose some of this information. Versioning may also help if the lookup key is different, but the lookup value is the same. Example: tax - you may have the same effective tax key, but the reason for setting it may be different. You can actually mix the 2 approaches: use versioning where keeping the versioned information yields additional business benefits and use denormalisation where not.

Comment: Okay I will have to think about it, thanks a lot for your input :)